# Android Facebook Share not showing description on facebook wall

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

When my app try to share something, the description is shown in the share activity, but it does not show up when it is posted. I went through many stackoverflow posts, but nothing could solve my problem.

Here is my call flow :

1. Share button is clicked
2. Activity calls a static method and passes itself and content to share to it via Bundle
3. Share activity is invoked from this static method. It displays the content to share correctly with all image, caption and description
4. Content is shared successfully
5. When the facebook post is checked, it just shows the playstore app details, with the image that I had set in 3, without the description

Here is the code that i use

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
     FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) 
    {
     FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
           .setLink("<playstore link>")
           .setApplicationName("<appname>")
           .setName("<some name>")
           .setCaption("<some text>")
           .setDescription("a description")
           .setPicture("http://url/to/image.jpg")
           .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }
```

But sharing the same using FeedDialog works

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("name", "name");
                    params.putString("caption", "caption");
                    params.putString("description","desc");
                    params.putString("link", "playstore link");
                    params.putString("picture", "http://url/to/image.jpg");

                    WebDialog feedDialog = (
                        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity,
                                session,
                            params))
                        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {
                                if (error == null) {

                                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                    if (postId != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(activity,

                                            "Posted Successfully!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        activity.finish();
                                    } else {
                                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                            "Publish cancelled", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        activity.finish();
                                    }
                                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                    // User clicked the "x" button
                                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Publish cancelled", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    activity.finish();
                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "An Error Occurred", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    activity.finish();
                                }


                            }



                        })
                        .build();
                    feedDialog.show();
```

Thank You

Comment: have you sloved this. I am facing same issue. please share

Comment: I think it is a facebook sdk bug. For the time being, I omitted the ShareDialog and used FeedDialog. If you find a solution, please remember to update this thread

Comment: thanks for response. I was thinking so. I have started the bounty. Let see.

Comment: Use Updated Facebook API, And follow there steps

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain thanks for comment. I just updated the facebook sdk too to latest one. but didn't helped :(

Comment: same problem here. If you solve this problem please let us know. By the way I asked similar question before you. You can check my codes and steps if you want. I have a interest situation here 4.4.4 doesn't open facebook app, 4.4.2 it works like a charm, 4.0.1 (API 15) doesn't show anyting :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328377/facebook-android-sdk-sharedialog-doesnt-work

Comment: Which facebook SDK are you using ? I have observed that the some of the features of latest SDK doesn't work out until you don't have the app in the play store.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)  (Versions 4.0+)

> To show the ShareDialog for a link in your activity, create a
>   ShareDialog instance in your onCreate method:
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
>     CallbackManager callbackManager;
>     ShareDialog shareDialog;
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
>         callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
>         shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
>         // this part is optional
>         shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { ... });
>     }
> ```
>
> Then show the ShareDialog:
>
> ```
> if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
>     ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
>             .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
>             .setContentDescription(
>                     "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
>             .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
>             .build();
>
>     shareDialog.show(linkContent);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Slartibartfast's Answer is working fine until  `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'`

From Facebook SDK version 4.25.0

`setContentTitle("") setContentDescription("")` is depricated. 
You have to use `setQuote("");` Method instead of `setContentDescription("");`

For more detail about depreciation Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android