# Facebook Android SDK ShareDialog doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity, share

I have a strange problem with Facebook Android SDK 4.0. I added all permissions,API_KEY and Hashkeys double checked they are OK. But I can't use ShareDialog on my Real Device which is API 15 and GenyMotion 4.4.4, 4.4.2.

When I try to open ShareDialog it appears without my content. It opens empty on my real device. But it works perfectly on GenyMotion 4.2.1, I tried to open GenyMotion 4.4.4 and 4.4.2 but these emulators don't open Facebook App. They are redirecting me to web view. When I enter my information on the webview I can see my all content so it's working again.

How can it be ? My Real Device doesn't post anything but GenyMotion 4.2.1 does work fine ? What is the problem ?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".GlobalState"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.vet" >

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider351533225052233"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/API_KEY" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

This is my Application class;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(this, "KEY", "KEY");

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

}
```

This is my MainActivity.class;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_harita, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setupMap();
    //showGPSDisableAlert();

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_share) {
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                    .setContentTitle("vet !")
                                    .setContentDescription(
                                            "asd")
                                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://facebook.com/vet"))
                                    .build();

                            shareDialog.show(linkContent);}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you !

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What's the Facebook app version on your device? For 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 genymotion emulators, do you have the FB app installed, but it's not opening?

Comment: My Facebook apps are up to date. I downloaded from Google Store in my GenyMotion and my genymotion emulators are up to date too. Yes I have the FB on genymotions and real device but it's not opening 4.4.4 and 4.4.2 its working 4.2.1 like a charm. I didn't understand why ?

Comment: And you're able to run the FB app in your 4.4.4 and 4.4.2 devices without problems?

Comment: I can able to run the FB on genymotion when i click the FB App itself. But I can't share my faceook dialog to FB app from my application when I run 4.4.4 or 4.4.2. It directs to web services.It should be genymotion problem. But I didn't understand my real device opens facebook but doesn't show my sharedialog message which is 4.0.1 (API 15), genymotion 4.2.1 opens FB from my app and shows my share dialog perfectly. It's really annoying.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your facebook app on the real device, then put Log.i() message to get log from facebook api
Try also to empty the application cache memory and reinstall it.
In parallel try to test this sample application from facebook SDK
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/Scrumptious

Comment: I did everything still same.